# Can't read the data of all lines

Tags: c++, file-io

My code can't read data of all lines.

```
void read(string name, student *sv, int n) {
ifstream file (name, ios::in);
string name, sex;
int dy, mth, year, i = 0;
float a, b;
while (file >> name >> dy >> mth >> year >> sex >> a >> b) {
    cout << name << dy << mth << year << sex <<  a <<  b << endl;
    sv[i].name = name;
    sv[i].date.day = dy;
    sv[i].date.month = mth;
    sv[i].date.year = name;
    sv[i].sex = sex;
    sv[i].math = a;
    sv[i].physics = b;
    ++i;
}
file.close();
```

My data:

```
Johns 3 6 1999 Male 5 7
Jeam  3 7 1998 Male 8 7
Jes   7 9 1999 Male 5 9
```

When I debug this code, it can't read last line ( Jes   7 9 1999 Male 5 9 ). So struct sv haven't last value.

Comment: Does your input file have a line break (\n or \r\n) at the end of the last line?

Comment: This in essence should work fine. I don't know where the variable "nam" comes from or what the d.close() is doing. I also strongly argue against shadowing the variable name, but if your *sv points to an appropriately sized array the loop in essence should work.

Comment: The last line haven't a line break, just have " endl " same other lines.
Thanks Oncaphiilis. But, my code was edited. 
How to read last line with while ( filename >> variable ){ } syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is this line:

```
while (file >> name >> dy >> mth >> year >> sex >> a >> b) {
```

when you reach the last line of the file you read all those variables but also you reach the end of the file so the whole expression converts to false and you will not execute code in while for the last line

Try something like this:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(file, line);
while (file && !line.empty())
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;

    //parse line and do stuff

    std::getline(file, line);
}
```

Comment: I don't know that way....
That way, how to assign values which read from file,  into new variables...
Ex: read  (Johns 3 6 1999 Male 5 7 ) line then name = John, day = 3, ....

Comment: You can use stringstream for it. stringstream usage is the same as for filestreams.
Read C++ documentation: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

Comment: Again, read the documentation. Here is another link containing example: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: void docfile(string namefile) {
 cout << "READ FILE" << endl;
 ifstream re(namefile, ios::in);
 string line;
 while (getline(re,line))
 {
  istringstream ss(line);
  string name, sex;
  int day, month, year;
  float one, two;
  ss >> name >> day >> month >> year >> sex >> one >> two;
   cout << name << day << month << year << sex << one << two << endl;
 }
 re.close();
}

It can't get value in lines =(

Comment: @J.Bie, give me output of your program or error message. This code seems ok (except of `using namespace std;`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// main.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct student {
  std::string name;
  std::string sex;
};

void read(std::string fname, student *sv) {
  std::ifstream file(fname.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
  std::string name, sex;
  int i = 0;
  while (file >> name >> sex) {
    std::cout << name << " " << sex << std::endl;
    sv[i].name = name;
    sv[i].sex = sex;
    ++i;
  }
  file.close();
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  student sv[10];
  std::string fname(argv[1]);
  read(fname, sv);
}
```

Build:

```
g++ -o test main.cpp
```

Test input file:

```
ABC Male
DEF Female
GHI Unknown
KLM Whoknows
```

Run:

```
./test test.txt
```

Output:

```
ABC Male
DEF Female
GHI Unknown
KLM Whoknows
4
```

Comment: @J.Bie Which part don't you understand? (bạn ko hiểu chỗ nào?)

Comment: Build: g++ -o test main.cpp

Comment: Em test code như bro thì nó không nhận ạ =((  tại sao phải dùng trực tiếp std:: mà không khai báo using namespace std; ngay từ đầu ạ?

Comment: @J.Bie Bạn dùng gì để build? Mình đang nói dùng g++ tren Linux. Còn bạn dùng `using namespace std;` thì cũng được mà. Mình thì thích dùng cùng với `std` vì với dự án lớn và cho nhiều platform (mobile, linux, windows) có thể họ sẽ có những tên trùng, dùng `std` để chỉ rõ là mình dùng thư viện chuẩn của C++.

Comment: à vâng =) em dùng VS của Win ạ =) cám ơn bro nhiều ạ